# How to delete unnecessary resistances in a resistance network

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I'm still dealing with resistance network processing and got
one problem left: how to delete unnecessary resistances?

---

### Background

Let's assume we are junior high students and know nothing about Kirchhoff's laws. We only know about how to calculate parallel resistances

[image: parallel]

equivalent serial resistances

[image: line]

and how to convert between star- and triangle topologies

[image: conv]

However, the first step of the calculation process is to determine which resistances are relevant and which are not (when looking at the equivalent resistance between some points in the network). At this I got stuck.

---

### Main Problem

***From now on I'll use edges in graphs to represent resistances***

Some resistance's existence contribute nothing to the entire network:

For example, when calculating resistance between point 1 and point 4 in this network:

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 5 <-> 2, 6 <-> 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {0, 2}, {3, 2}}]
```

[image: net1]

point 5 and point 6 is totally useless, So I want a program to delete edge `5<->2` and `6<->3` as well as vertex 5 and 6, generate a graph like this:

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}}]
```

[image: net2]

A more complex form can be like:

```
 Graph[{0 <-> 13, 13 <-> 14, 14 <-> 0, 0 <-> 1, 12 <-> 1, 0 <-> 12, 
   10 <-> 16, 4 <-> 9, 9 <-> 10, 10 <-> 4, 11 <-> 9, 11 <-> 10, 
   1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 4 <-> 8, 8 <-> 7, 
   5 <-> 7, 6 <-> 3, 7 <-> 3, 11 <-> 4, 12 <-> 17, 17 <-> 18, 
   18 <-> 19, 4 <-> 15, 15 <-> 20, 20 <-> 4, 10 <-> 21}]
```

[image: net3]

With resistances between **point 1, 3 and 11** concerned.

The final result of this test graph shall be

```
Graph[{4 <-> 9, 9 <-> 10, 10 <-> 4, 11 <-> 9, 11 <-> 10, 1 <-> 2, 
  2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 4 <-> 8, 8 <-> 7, 5 <-> 7, 
  6 <-> 3, 7 <-> 3, 11 <-> 4}]
```

[image: net4]

---

### Some Notes

I'm trying to write things out using only methods in graph theory or similar techniques, thus it's not desired to use Kirchhoff's laws or solve the network via classical network analysis. Any other way involving list-manipulation, graph manipulation, etc. are acceptable.

Comment: If anything left unclear, comment anytime~

Comment: I will appreciate a good solution a ton, as I've been trying to solve this problem for days. And also, this is the last piece of this big program. I'll contribute the code when the program is eventually completed.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by _resistences between point 1, 3 and 11_. Isn't the resistance only defined between two individual points; for that problem I think I found a solution

Comment: I can't write a complete answer for now, but I once had a similar problem and removed "single dead ends" (19-12,16-10,...) as follows: //1. Create adjacency matrix. 2. Check for vertices connected only to one point. 3. Remove them. 4. Repeat. // For the other ones (e.g. 14-13-0-12) you should find another algorithm.

Comment: The restriction to graph theory seems a bit strange, since the algebra is straightforward, especially in _Mathematica_ with `Eliminate`. And, of course, the algebra can take you other places...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if this completely answers your question; if not I hope it at least gets you further to an actual solution

Take for instance the second of the two networks you presented

```
g = Graph[{0 <-> 13, 13 <-> 14, 14 <-> 0, 0 <-> 1, 12 <-> 1, 0 <-> 12,
10 <-> 16, 4 <-> 9, 9 <-> 10, 10 <-> 4, 11 <-> 9, 11 <-> 10, 
1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 4 <-> 8, 8 <-> 7, 
5 <-> 7, 6 <-> 3, 7 <-> 3, 11 <-> 4, 12 <-> 17, 17 <-> 18, 
18 <-> 19, 4 <-> 15, 15 <-> 20, 20 <-> 4, 10 <-> 21}, 
VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: original network]

with `FindPath` you can find all routes between two points in your network (**1** and **11** in this case) as follows

```
sol = FindPath[g, 1, 11, Infinity, All]
```

A simple visualization for this could be

```
Manipulate[HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[sol[[n]]]], {n, 1, Length@sol, 1}]
```

[image: animated gif]

To get the network containing only the relevant nodes you could use `Subgraph` as in

```
Subgraph[g, sol // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: network]

Comment: Well, it seems that I missed this method of direcly find paths~ Allow me to think for one day and confirm the correctness of this method before I select this.

Comment: Very very helpful! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that implements your rules. Its argument is a list of `r[i,j,v]` dummy functions that denote a resistance `v` between points `i`and `j`.

2) Parallel resistances:

```
network[a___, r[i_, j_, v1_], b___, r[i_, j_, v2_], c___] :=network[r[i, j, v1 v2/(v1 + v2)], a, b, c]
network[a___, r[i_, j_, v1_], b___, r[j_, i_, v2_], c___] :=network[r[i, j, v1 v2/(v1 + v2)], a, b, c]
```

2) Sequential resistances, get read of vertex in the middle if it is not connected to a third vertex:

```
 network[a___, r[j_, i_, v1_], b___, r[j_, k_, v2_], c___] :=
  network[r[i, k, v1 + v2], a, b, c] /;Length[Cases[{a, b, c}, r[___, j, ___]]] == 0
network[a___, r[j_, i_, v1_], b___, r[k_, j_, v2_], c___] := 
 network[r[i, k, v1 + v2], a, b, c] /;Length[Cases[{a, b, c}, r[___, j, ___]]] == 0
network[a___, r[i_, j_, v1_], b___, r[j_, k_, v2_], c___] := 
 network[r[i, k, v1 + v2], a, b, c] /;Length[Cases[{a, b, c}, r[___, j, ___]]] == 0
network[a___, r[i_, j_, v1_], b___, r[k_, j_, v2_], c___] := 
 network[r[i, k, v1 + v2], a, b, c] /;Length[Cases[{a, b, c}, r[___, j, ___]]] == 0
```

### Example

```
network[r[1, 2, a], r[2, 3, b], r[3, 4, c], r[4, 5, d], r[2, 4, e]]
(*network[r[1, 5, a + d + ((b + c) e)/(b + c + e)]]*)
```

[image]

For more complicated examples star-triangle transformation rule have to be implemented.

Comment: ererer, I don't mean this, What you've done I've done it, so please focus on my problem of deleting unnecessary things :) Also, when dealing with more complex networks, this approach will be quite slow, and the visulization process of this method will be hard due to the structure of your program.

Comment: @Wjx Actually I would be glad to help, but perhaps I've not fully understood your question. At first your say "Some resistence's existence contribute nothing to the entire network", but then you focus on the path between 1 and 4. Why is that? Why do you think the pass between 5 and 6 is less important? Maybe you should specify more precisely what you want. Also as Sascha has already pointed out, what is exact meaning of "resistances between points 1, 3 and 11" ?

Comment: by saying resistence between points, I mean to derive a simplified resistence network consists only of these three points which can fully simulates the original network's behaviour, so when only two points are endpoints, I need to get a graph with two points and one resistence, but when more than 2 points is presented, I need to get a part of FullGraph which use weight to specify the resistence.

Comment: check this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124528/how-to-simplify-a-resistence-network-and-represent-the-simplifying-process/124529#124529 maybe you can add another solution too~