# How to simplify a resistence network and represent the simplifying process?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, graphs-and-networks, visualization

Through out our study from junior high to freshman year, we need to deal with complex resistence networks and know about how to solve them. There're three principle rules of them:

1. when dealing with line form resistences, sum them up.
2. when dealing with parallel resistences, do `1/Total[1/rlist]`.
3. when dealing with complex networks, use transformation between triangle and star form.

How to create a program that illustrate a human like resistence network solving process in Mathematica using only the previous three rules?

Answer (score 11):

## Result

A slight view of the result first:

[image: res]

[image: anim]

---

## Code and Explanation

Firstly, let's write out some visulization rules we'll use later:

```
style = {VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Red, ImageSize->Medium};

vc[g_] := 
  VertexCoordinates -> (# -> 
       PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ VertexList@g);

highstyle[color_, ver_, edge_] := {Style[#, Darker[color, .65]] & /@ ver, 
   Style[#, Darker@color, Thick] & /@ edge};

delhighlight[g_] := 
  Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, GraphHighlight -> False] &, g, 
   PropertyValue[g, GraphHighlight]];
```

Where `style` specify the overall styling, `vc` can be used to keep the graph in it's original shape after modification, `highstyle` specify the overall highlight style and `delhighlight` delete all highlight style and prepare the graph for further simplification.

Then we can generate a quite beautiful image of a certain complex resistence network:

```
SeedRandom@1;
g = Graph[#, EdgeWeight -> RandomInteger[{1, 10}, EdgeCount@#]] &@
  Graph[{0 <-> 13, 13 <-> 14, 14 <-> 0, 0 <-> 1, 12 <-> 1, 0 <-> 12, 
    10 <-> 16, 4 <-> 9, 9 <-> 10, 10 <-> 4, 11 <-> 9, 11 <-> 10, 
    1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 4 <-> 8, 8 <-> 7, 
    5 <-> 7, 6 <-> 3, 7 <-> 3, 11 <-> 4, 12 <-> 17, 17 <-> 18, 
    18 <-> 19, 4 <-> 15, 15 <-> 20, 20 <-> 4, 10 <-> 21}, 
   GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", style]

pt = {1, 8, 9};
```

where `g` will be the graph to process and `pt` specify the points concerned, so in this case with three vertexes names' in pt, I mean to eventually get a graph with three vertexes only and know how they're connected.

[image: g]

Then, for the notoriously bugsome Mathematica's Graph functions, I need to write out some code to replicate some existing functions:

```
myVertexDelete[g_, ptl_] := 
 Block[{ea = 
    Association[# -> PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ 
      EdgeList@g], el}, 
  Graph[el = EdgeList@VertexDelete[g, ptl], EdgeWeight -> ea /@ el, 
   style, VertexCoordinates -> (# -> 
        PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ 
      Complement[VertexList@g, ptl])]]
```

`myVertexDelete` will properly delete vertexes while preserving other properties correctly.

```
mergep[resl_, cg_: True] := 
 Block[{prep = #[[1, 1]] -> 1/Total[1/#[[;; , 2]]] & /@ 
     GatherBy[resl, Sort@#[[1]] &]}, 
  Graph[prep[[;; , 1]], EdgeWeight -> prep[[;; , 2]], style, 
   If[cg =!= True, vc@cg, Automatic]]]
```

`mergep` merges parallel resistences to aviod Mathematica's wierd behaviour when dealing with complex graphs as mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124228/how-to-assign-edgeweight-to-a-non-simple-graph).

Then we can go on and teach Mathematica how to process simple resistence networks contains only parallel positioned or line formed resistences:

```
mline[g_] := 
  Block[{vn = VertexList@g, vd = VertexDegree@g, 
    ea = Association@
      Thread[EdgeList@g -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]], r, subg}, 
   r = UndirectedEdge @@ Complement[VertexComponent[g, #, 1], #] -> 
       Total[ea /@ EdgeList[g, (Alternatives @@ #) <-> _]] & /@ 
     ConnectedComponents[
      subg = Subgraph[g, 
        Complement[Pick[vn, vd, 2], pt]]]; {HighlightGraph[g, 
     highstyle[Green, VertexList@subg, 
      EdgeList[g, (Alternatives @@ VertexList@subg) <-> _]], style], 
    HighlightGraph[
     mergep[Join[# -> ea@# & /@ 
        EdgeList@VertexDelete[g, VertexList@subg], r], g], 
     Style[#, Darker[Green, .65], Thick] & /@ 
      DeleteDuplicates[r[[;; , 1]]]]}];

simpleproc[g_] := 
  Most@NestWhileList[mline@*delhighlight@*Last, {g}, 
    Unequal @@ (Sort@*EdgeList /@ #) &];
```

Where `mline` merges line form resistences and represent them, and simple proc will repeatedly try to simplify the network untill it cannot be further simplified using simple network's manipulation rules.

Let's try it out with this simple graph:

```
gg = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 8, 4 <-> 6, 
   5 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8}, 
  EdgeWeight -> RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 9], style]
pt = {1, 7};
simpleproc[gg]
```

[image: tryout]

the effect is great and the result is correct.

Then we need to know how to proceed with these two forms of transformation: star->triangle and triangle->star:

```
s2t[r : {r1_, r2_, r3_}] := (RotateRight[r].r)/r;
t2s[r : {r23_, r13_, r12_}] := RotateRight@r RotateLeft@r/Total@r
```

First thing first: how to transform between these two physically, where `s2t` stands for "star to triangle" and `t2s` do just the opposite:

[image: triangle to star]

[image: star to triangle]

then write out the code using these two rules:

```
simplifybypoints[g_, center_] := 
  Block[{adj, 
    ea = Association@
      Thread[EdgeList@g -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]], newedge}, 
   adj = Complement[VertexComponent[g, center, 1], {center}]; 
   newedge = 
    UndirectedEdge @@@ 
     Thread[{RotateRight@adj, RotateLeft@adj}]; {HighlightGraph[g, 
     highstyle[Purple, Append[adj, center], Thread[adj <-> center]]], 
    HighlightGraph[
     mergep[Join[# -> ea@# & /@ EdgeList@VertexDelete[g, center], 
       Thread[newedge -> 
         s2t[PropertyValue[{g, UndirectedEdge[#, center]}, 
             EdgeWeight] & /@ adj]]], g], 
     highstyle[Darker@Purple, adj, newedge]]}];

simplifybycycle[g_, cycle_] := 
 Block[{newp = Unique["new"], 
   ea = Association@
     Thread[EdgeList@g -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]], 
   el = EdgeList@EdgeDelete[g, cycle], vl = VertexList@Graph@cycle, 
   newedge}, {HighlightGraph[g, highstyle[Purple, vl, cycle]], 
   HighlightGraph[
    Graph[Join[el, 
      newedge = 
       Thread[newp <-> Complement[vl, #][[1]] & /@ List @@@ cycle]], 
     EdgeWeight -> 
      Join[ea /@ el, 
       t2s[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ cycle]], style, 
     VertexCoordinates -> 
      Append[# -> PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ 
        VertexList@g, 
       newp -> Mean[
         PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ vl]]], 
    highstyle[Darker@Purple, {newp}, newedge]]}]
```

and we can use `complexproc` to integrate these two nasty functions as both of them must be used to solve arbitrary networks:

```
complexproc[g_] := 
  Block[{cycle, center}, 
   If[(cycle = FindCycle[Graph@EdgeList@g, {3}]) === {}, 
    If[(center = 
        SelectFirst[
         Thread[{VertexList@g, VertexDegree@g}], #[[2]] == 3 && 
           FreeQ[pt, #[[1]]] &]) === {}, {g, g}, 
     simplifybypoints[delhighlight@g, center[[1]]]], 
    simplifybycycle[delhighlight@g, cycle[[1]]]]];
```

When there's cycles, simplify by cycle using `simplifybycycle`. If not, check if there's any star form resistences, yes? use `simplifybypoints`. no? probably the whole simplify process is over~

one sample is like the following:

```
gg = Graph[{1 <-> center, 2 <-> center, 3 <-> center, other <-> 1, 
   4 <-> 3, 5 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5}, EdgeWeight -> Range@7, style, 
  ImageSize -> Small, GraphLayout -> "RadialDrawing"]
complexproc@gg
simplifybypoints[gg, center]
```

[image: sample]

Then sometimes we may need to simplify the graph and delete unnecessary vertexes and edges, for this part, I mainly copied from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124479/6084) but I added some minor adjustments so that it can work for situations with more vertexes(>2) in `pt`:

```
delline[g_] := 
 Block[{del = 
    Complement[VertexList@g, 
     DeleteDuplicates@
      Flatten[FindPath[g, First@pt, #, Infinity, All] & /@ 
        Rest@pt]]}, {HighlightGraph[g, 
    highstyle[Orange, del, 
     Flatten[Thread[
         DeleteCases[VertexComponent[g, #, 1], #] <-> #] & /@ del]]], 
   myVertexDelete[g, del]}]
```

The final thing is easy, repeatingly use `simpleproc` and `complexproc`:

```
allproc[g_] := 
 Grid[Select[Flatten[
     NestWhileList[
      Block[{res = simpleproc@#[[-1, -1]], res1}, 
        res1 = complexproc@res[[-1, -1]];
        Join[
         res, {res1, delline@delhighlight@res1[[-1]]}]] &, {delline@
        g}, ! SubsetQ[pt, VertexList@#[[-1, -1]]] &], 1], 
    Length@# == 2 && ! IsomorphicGraphQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &], 
  Spacings -> {5, 5}]
```

Then we can get an optimal result.

---

## Final Code

```
Clear["`*"]
SeedRandom@1;
g = Graph[#, EdgeWeight -> RandomInteger[{1, 10}, EdgeCount@#]] &@
  Graph[{0 <-> 13, 13 <-> 14, 14 <-> 0, 0 <-> 1, 12 <-> 1, 0 <-> 12, 
    10 <-> 16, 4 <-> 9, 9 <-> 10, 10 <-> 4, 11 <-> 9, 11 <-> 10, 
    1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 4 <-> 8, 8 <-> 7, 
    5 <-> 7, 6 <-> 3, 7 <-> 3, 11 <-> 4, 12 <-> 17, 17 <-> 18, 
    18 <-> 19, 4 <-> 15, 15 <-> 20, 20 <-> 4, 10 <-> 21}, 
   GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", EdgeLabelStyle -> Red, 
   ImageSize -> Medium]

pt = {1, 8, 9};

style = {VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotRange -> 
    MinMax /@ 
     Transpose[
      PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ VertexList@g]};
vc[g_] := 
  VertexCoordinates -> (# -> 
       PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ VertexList@g);
highstyle[color_, ver_, 
   edge_] := {Style[#, Darker[color, .65]] & /@ ver, 
   Style[#, Darker@color, Thick] & /@ edge};

delhighlight[g_] := 
  Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, GraphHighlight -> False] &, g, 
   PropertyValue[g, GraphHighlight]];

myVertexDelete[g_, ptl_] := 
 Block[{ea = 
    Association[# -> PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ 
      EdgeList@g], el}, 
  Graph[el = EdgeList@VertexDelete[g, ptl], EdgeWeight -> ea /@ el, 
   style, VertexCoordinates -> (# -> 
        PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ 
      Complement[VertexList@g, ptl])]]


delline[g_] := 
  Block[{del = 
     Complement[VertexList@g, 
      DeleteDuplicates@
       Flatten[FindPath[g, First@pt, #, Infinity, All] & /@ 
         Rest@pt]]}, {HighlightGraph[g, 
     highstyle[Orange, del, 
      Flatten[Thread[
          DeleteCases[VertexComponent[g, #, 1], #] <-> #] & /@ del]]],
     myVertexDelete[g, del]}];

mergep[resl_, cg_: True] := 
  Block[{prep = #[[1, 1]] -> 1/Total[1/#[[;; , 2]]] & /@ 
      GatherBy[resl, Sort@#[[1]] &]}, 
   Graph[prep[[;; , 1]], EdgeWeight -> prep[[;; , 2]], style, 
    If[cg =!= True, vc@cg, Automatic]]];

mline[g_] := 
  Block[{vn = VertexList@g, vd = VertexDegree@g, 
    ea = Association@
      Thread[EdgeList@g -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]], r, subg}, 
   r = UndirectedEdge @@ Complement[VertexComponent[g, #, 1], #] -> 
       Total[ea /@ EdgeList[g, (Alternatives @@ #) <-> _]] & /@ 
     ConnectedComponents[
      subg = Subgraph[g, 
        Complement[Pick[vn, vd, 2], pt]]]; {HighlightGraph[g, 
     highstyle[Green, VertexList@subg, 
      EdgeList[g, (Alternatives @@ VertexList@subg) <-> _]], style], 
    HighlightGraph[
     mergep[Join[# -> ea@# & /@ 
        EdgeList@VertexDelete[g, VertexList@subg], r], g], 
     Style[#, Darker[Green, .65], Thick] & /@ 
      DeleteDuplicates[r[[;; , 1]]]]}];

simpleproc[g_] := 
  Most@NestWhileList[mline@*delhighlight@*Last, {g}, 
    Unequal @@ (Sort@*EdgeList /@ #) &];

s2t[r : {r1_, r2_, r3_}] := (RotateRight[r].r)/r;
t2s[r : {r23_, r13_, r12_}] := RotateRight@r RotateLeft@r/Total@r

simplifybypoints[g_, center_] := 
  Block[{adj, 
    ea = Association@
      Thread[EdgeList@g -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]], newedge}, 
   adj = Complement[VertexComponent[g, center, 1], {center}]; 
   newedge = 
    UndirectedEdge @@@ 
     Thread[{RotateRight@adj, RotateLeft@adj}]; {HighlightGraph[g, 
     highstyle[Purple, Append[adj, center], Thread[adj <-> center]]], 
    HighlightGraph[
     mergep[Join[# -> ea@# & /@ EdgeList@VertexDelete[g, center], 
       Thread[newedge -> 
         s2t[PropertyValue[{g, UndirectedEdge[#, center]}, 
             EdgeWeight] & /@ adj]]], g], 
     highstyle[Darker@Purple, adj, newedge]]}];

simplifybycycle[g_, cycle_] := 
 Block[{newp = Unique["new"], 
   ea = Association@
     Thread[EdgeList@g -> PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]], 
   el = EdgeList@EdgeDelete[g, cycle], vl = VertexList@Graph@cycle, 
   newedge}, {HighlightGraph[g, highstyle[Purple, vl, cycle]], 
   HighlightGraph[
    Graph[Join[el, 
      newedge = 
       Thread[newp <-> Complement[vl, #][[1]] & /@ List @@@ cycle]], 
     EdgeWeight -> 
      Join[ea /@ el, 
       t2s[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ cycle]], style, 
     VertexCoordinates -> 
      Append[# -> PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ 
        VertexList@g, 
       newp -> Mean[
         PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ vl]]], 
    highstyle[Darker@Purple, {newp}, newedge]]}]

complexproc[g_] := 
  Block[{cycle, center}, 
   If[(cycle = FindCycle[Graph@EdgeList@g, {3}]) === {}, 
    If[(center = 
        SelectFirst[
         Thread[{VertexList@g, VertexDegree@g}], #[[2]] == 3 && 
           FreeQ[pt, #[[1]]] &]) === {}, {g, g}, 
     simplifybypoints[delhighlight@g, center[[1]]]], 
    simplifybycycle[delhighlight@g, cycle[[1]]]]];


allproc[g_] := 
  Grid[Select[
    Flatten[NestWhileList[
      Block[{res = simpleproc@#[[-1, -1]], res1}, 
        res1 = complexproc@res[[-1, -1]];
        Join[
         res, {res1, delline@delhighlight@res1[[-1]]}]] &, {delline@
        g}, ! SubsetQ[pt, VertexList@#[[-1, -1]]] &], 1], 
    Length@# == 2 && ! IsomorphicGraphQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &], 
   Spacings -> {5, 5}];

dynamicproc[g_] := 
 ListAnimate@
  Flatten[Select[
    Flatten[NestWhileList[
      Block[{res = simpleproc@#[[-1, -1]], res1}, 
        res1 = complexproc@res[[-1, -1]];
        Join[
         res, {res1, delline@delhighlight@res1[[-1]]}]] &, {delline@
        g}, ! SubsetQ[pt, VertexList@#[[-1, -1]]] &], 1], 
    Length@# == 2 && ! IsomorphicGraphQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &], 1]
```

then go on and see the simplification process by:

```
(*Grid form*)allproc@g
(*Animation form*)dynamicproc@g
```

Comment: zhi chi yi ge. rep zhe me duo le a

Comment: :) xie xie zhi chi, zui jin you ji tian rep bao peng le, suo yi zhang de kuai ;)

Comment: gao zhong sheng neng you zhe ge shui ping, li hai ya!

Comment: @ShutaoTang wei shen me hui tie li mian dou zai shuo han yu pin yin?

Comment: xian shou cang le,you shi jian zai kan kan. :)